# Finding tangent plane to a surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

Given the surface $ xyz = 16 $ I have to find the tangent plane that is perpendicular to 
$$
(x,y,z)^T = (1,2,3)^T + t(1,2,4)^T, \quad t \in \mathbb{R}. 
$$

I have tried to find the gradient of the surface equation and equate it to $(1,2,3)$, an then finding the tangent point(s) and then finding the intercept. However, I get the wrong answer.

Comment: Your "tangent point" $(2\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$ is not on the surface because it does not satisfy the equation $xyz=16$. Also, can you clarify what you mean by a tangent plane "in the same direction as"? Do you mean you are looking for a tangent plane that is perpendicular to the line (i.e. with normal $(1,2,4)$), or do you mean a tangent plane parallel to the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean your tangent plane should be *normal* to the given line, you are looking for a point where the normal to the surface (i.e., the gradient) is parallel to the direction vector of the line. That is, your point $(x,y,z)$ satisfies

\begin{align*}
yz &= 1\lambda \\
xz &= 2\lambda \\
xy &= 4\lambda
\end{align*}
for some nonzero $\lambda$.

The point also satisfies $xyz=16$, so you get

\begin{align*}
16 &= \lambda x \\
16 &= 2\lambda y \\
16 &= 4\lambda z
\end{align*}
Solving this yields $x=4z$ and $y=2z$, and since $xyz=16$ we get
\begin{align*}
8z^3&=16\\
\end{align*}
So the point must be $(4\sqrt[3]{2},2\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2})$